# How do find web config file of Claims Based authentication?

Tags: 2010, web-part, claims-based-auth

I want Configuring claims and forms based authentication for use with an LDAP provider in SharePoint 2010.

I change webcomfig file of :

1.Adjust the web.config of the Central Administration site

\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\ Port_Number_of_Central_Administration — The web.config file that defines configuration settings for the SharePoint Central Administration application.

2.Adjust the web.config of the Security Token Service (STS) virtual directory

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\WebServices\SecurityToken

3.Adjust the web.config of the claims based web application

**How do find web config file of Claims Based authentication ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web.config of the Central Administration site  :

IIS\SharePoint Central Administration v4\Explore
\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\ Port_Number_of_Central_Administration

web.config of the claims based web application
\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\ Port_Number_of_WebApplication

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand your question, you are looking for the location of the web-application web.config file, right? That file is also located in the Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories folder - usually in a subfolder named after the port number assigned to the web-app. 
You should be able to determine which folder referes to your web-app by looking at the web site list under IIS Manager - from here opening the folder is a simple matter of clicking the explore button. See also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms474356%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Pleave a comment if you need further detail or if I have missunderstood you question.

Comment: Yes , Thanks . so Web.config File Locations
 of the Central Administration site ?

Comment: Sorry, saw this post only now. I'm not sure I have understood your question. You need to locate the web.config file for the Central Admin site ? That would be in the \Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\ Port_Number_of_Central_Administration folder, as you indicated in your question. Or are you having problems in determining what you must insert in aforementioned files??

Comment: I want Configuring claims and forms based authentication for use with an LDAP provider in SharePoint 2010.I should change 3 web.config file : how do find they ? (I have 10 web application , this file is same of all web application ?)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to find the web.config file it to open the IIS Manager > Sites > right click the IIS Site > Explore. A exporer window will open at the location where you will find the file.

[image]